# Persist conntrack database across reboots

Tags: linux, debian, router, nat, conntrack

I run a NAT router on Debian 10 which takes only a few seconds to reboot, way less then 120 seconds, more like 3. I'd like to keep established connections so that a reboot of the router does not break natted TCP connections, but I don't have the capacities to run two synching routers. How do I persist the conntrack tables on a single machine?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out, it does not work right now with packaged versions of the conntrack-tools, but it works with the not yet released changes. This [commit](https://git.netfilter.org/conntrack-tools/commit/?id=1c596b9ec8f26ee5e044e033509e656e8376a395) introduces a save output format which will write the `conntrack` command line parameters needed to restore the conntrack tables. With this information it's easy to persist the tables. Unfortunately, it is unreleased. Building the conntrack-tools is easy, but it requires an up-to-date version of libnetfilter-conntrack which then might clash with system utilities that depend on a different version.